# Which of the following statements is NOT true for a square matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra

Which of the following statements is NOT true for a square matrix A?

(a)If A is an upper triangular matrix, the eigenvalues of A are the diagonal elements of it.

(b) If A is real symmetric, the eigenvalues of A are always real and positive.

(c) If A is real, the eigenvalues of A and Transpose(A) are always the same.

(d) If all the principal minors of A are positive, all the eigenvalues of A are also positive.

I am confirmed about (a) and (d) but confused between (c) and (b). Please help.

Comment: for $b$ consider the matrix $-I$. Also I believe eigenvalue is one word not two.

Answer (score 2):

b) Consider the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-2\end{pmatrix}$$

(Actually, even $\begin{pmatrix}-1\end{pmatrix}$ is enough.)

c) Diagonalize the matrix as

$$A=PDP^{-1}.$$

Now, $$A^T=P^{-T}D^TP^T=QDQ^{-1}$$ because $D=D^T$.

Answer (score 0):

a) True. The equation of the eigenvalues $\det(A-\lambda\mathbb{I})=0$ returns the diagonal elements.

b) False. The eigenvalues are all real, but not necessarily positive. $A=0$ or $A=-3\mathbb{I}$ are counterexamples.

c) True. The equations for the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^T$ are the same because
$\det Q=\det Q^T$ for all matrices Q.

d) False: Consider the following counterexample $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&0\\ \end{pmatrix}$. It has complex eigenvalues. The statement will be true if in addition we require $A$ to be real and symmetric. Note that in the counterexample $A$ is real but not symmetric.